# Apple iPhone - debugging with console - <private>?

Tags: ios, iphone, macos, debugging, oslog

I'm using Console to debug iPhone 7

- I am seeing `<private>` on most information. I am able to access Xcode simulator iPhone 7 device which does not show `<private>`. However I need to debug a passkit pass on the phone.

I think my devices development certificate is in keychain - am I being stupid?

How do you debug a real iPhone with access to full information ?

Comment: Jailbroken users might find this helpful: https://github.com/EthanArbuckle/unredact-private-os_logs

Answer (score 40):

The  detail is coming from [Apple's Unified logging](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/os/logging?language=objc).
If a debug message is a dynamic string, by default, `<private>` will be displayed.

In order for the data to print out the actual string, the string must be declared `public` when sent to logging. For example, in Swift this will display the text sent to the logger, as it's a static string:

```
static let logger = OSLog(subsystem: "com.company.myApp", category: "myCategory")
os_log(logger, "Some text that will display correctly");
```

However, this will display `Some string: <private>`

```
os_log(logger, "Some string: %s", "text that will display <private>")
```

In order for the text to display as expected, it would need to be declared with the `public` tag:

```
os_log(logger, "Some string: %{public}s", "text that will display as expected")
```

If you're simply looking at logs for 3rd party applications, then you're not going to be able to view the data, by default.

However, there are [some that report](https://georgegarside.com/blog/macos/sierra-console-private/) that it is possible to see the redacted data with the `log` command line utility:

```
sudo log config --mode "private_data:on"
```

To my knowledge, this is not documented by Apple.

## Post Catalina

Note that the above, undocumented switch was broken with the introduction of Catalina. However, it is now possible to reveal 'private' messages with a simple, signed configuration profile, as documented by Howard Oakley, [here](https://eclecticlight.co/2020/05/25/how-to-reveal-private-messages-in-the-log/)

Comment: Sorry, no. To my knowledge, this isn't available from php.

Comment: Does that `sudo log config --mode "private_data:on"` work for you? I also need to debug some Apple's process logs such as `apsd` and this `<private>` makes it a lot more difficult.

Comment: @Jan, it does. I just tried it with apsd; copied the line into Terminal and watched the output in Console, which changed to showing all data. Tested using the Developer Beta 9 of macOS 10.13

Comment: In my case, I'm trying to see the logs from iOS and not from a macOS app. Do you see the private logs from an iOS app?

Comment: @Jan, sorry, I don't have an iOS device to test this.

Comment: Note that the daily Swift-syntax-change now requires `os_log("Some string: %{public}s", log:logger, ...`

Comment: Is public only required in "production"? I'm confused why I can see the output of a dynamic string in Console.app when developing - I haven't specified the string as {public}. This makes sense, otherwise what is the point of ever specifying {public}, but it's not specified in the WWDC sessions or the documentation.

Comment: @Austin, what SDK are you building against?

Comment: @TheDarkKnight I think it was 10.14, I may have figured out what was going on but can't remember :S. I had a hard time getting `os_log` to work and display in console consistently.

Comment: You can now do this in Swift: `os_log("\(variable, privacy: .public)")`

Comment: thanks @TheDarkKnight and Howard Oakley!

Comment: @DavidLawson answer is my case! It same with

let logger = Logger()
logger.warning("\\(warning, privacy: .public)")

to see a real warning, not <private>

Answer (score 3):

There is no single setting that you can change for iOS logging as there is for macOS.

If you are running a beta version of iOS, the private log information seems to be collected, so that is one option.

The other option is to see if there is a profile on [this page](https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/profiles-and-logs/) that covers the logging you need.

Once you install the relevant profile you will see the previously `<private>` information appearing in the iOS console log.

In my case I was able to use the "Baseband" profile to enable caller id logging while working on a CallKit extension.

To disable the private logging you simply remove the profile from general settings on the device.

Answer (score 3):

You can add this to your `Info.plist` to not have the arguments redacted when you don't have a debugger attached:

```
<key>OSLogPreferences</key>
<dict>
    <key>your.subsystem.key.here</key>
    <dict>
        <key>your-category-here</key>
        <dict>
            <key>Enable-Private-Data</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

Comment: This actually seems to work, thank you! If only it were documented somewhere...

Comment: Like this documentation? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/os/logging/customizing_logging_behavior_while_debugging